# Confidence interval of population standard deviation using measurements with uncertainties

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let's say I have a sample of N measurements which I use to calculate the standard deviation of said sample:

$s=\sqrt{\frac{\sum{(x-\bar{x})^2}}{N-1}}$

I can use this value to place a 68% confidence interval on the population standard deviation:

$P(\sqrt{\frac{ks^2}{q_{0.84}}}<\sigma<\sqrt{\frac{ks^2}{q_{0.16}}})=0.68$,

where the coefficients of the confidence interval are calculated using the appropriate chi-squared distribution.

However, my individual measurements have uncertainties, which means that $s$ itself has an associated error (I am using the formulation from [Ahn & Fessler 2003](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.127.2352) to calculate it, although the choice is not critical here).

My question is: How do I incorporate the error on $s$ into the calculation of the confidence interval for the population standard deviation?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The CI you give in your second displayed equation is for normal data, which you fail to mention.
I am unable to view your link. Can you say more about the 'uncertainties' of the individual observations? If you have a reasonably large sample, perhaps
bootstrap CI would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I am assuming that my data are distributed normally. When I say that the measurements have uncertainties I mean that each value sampled from the parent distribution is not known precisely bu only within a given CI (e.g. $x = [350\pm 25, 280\pm 29, 316\pm 17, 380 \pm 40]$). The uncertainties are assumed to be Gaussian, as well. I have two problems with your suggested solution. The first is that your procedure still does not account for the uncertainty in the measurements. The second is that I am operating in a small sample regime (say, $n<10$).

Comment: Well, my t is more variable than std normal. Granted 10 may not be enough observations for a useful bootstrap. // If each $X_i$ has 'extra variance' (maybe $\approx 200$ judging from CIs), then maybe include that into the std error of your estimate for the final CI. // While we're discussing 'problems', Trying to help, but I have a couple of 'problems' with your question: it is still incomplete and unclear. And your link is from an unknown source, is infested with 'conditions' and tasteless pop-up ads, so I'm not willing to use it for fear of lurking malware.

Comment: Did not mean to offend using the word problem. I was just saying why that solution may not apply to my particular situation. // It is not important that you read the link, it's a paper on standard errors, but we can just sort the the solution out from scratch. // How to add the extra variance into the estimate of my final CI is precisely what I am asking :-) // If you could kindly specify what details are missing to make my question clearer and complete, I'll provide them

Comment: Variances from independent sources add. // Not offended by your comment, but your link is too much for my antivirus software and the ads are a bit overboard even for even my somewhat jaded sensibilities. // Generally best to ask clear and self-contained questions, summarizing key parts of your sources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of one kind of bootstrap CI for an unknown population standard deviation. Suppose I have $n=100$ observations.

To get data for a demonstration, I sample from a t distribution with $\nu = 12$ DF, hence $\sigma^2 = \nu/(\nu-2) = 12/10 = 1.2,$ $\sigma = \sqrt{1.2} = 1.0955.$  [You would
substitute your data for my `x`. Presumably, your data are modeled
to be nearly but not exactly normal, as mentioned in your question.]

```
set.seed(1114)
x = rt(100, 12)
s.obs = sd(x);  s.obs
[1] 1.102585

set.seed(2020)
d.re = replicate(5000, sd(sample(x,100,rep=T))/s.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
s.obs/UL
     97.5%      2.5% 
 0.9659272 1.3009683
```

Notice that the 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI $(0.966, 1.301)$ contains
the observed SD $S_{obs} = 1.1026$ of the data `x`.

**Brief rationale for bootstrap code:** If we knew the distribution of
$S/\sigma$ then we could get $L$ and $U$ such that
$P\left(L \le \frac{S}{\sigma}\le U\right) = 0.95.$ Then
a 95% CI for $\sigma$ would be of the form
$\left(\frac{S}{U}, \frac{S}{L}\right).$

In order to approximate the unknown distribution of $S/\sigma$ we enter the 'bootstrap world', temporarily using `s.obs` $(S_{obs})$ as a proxy for $\sigma.$
We take $B = 5000$ samples of size $n=100$ with replacement
from `x`. This is called re-sampling. Then we obtain standard deviations $S^*$ of these samples and divide by `s.obs`
to get an idea of the unknown distribution of $D^*\approx S/\sigma.$
We take upper and lower quantiles $U^*, L^*$ of the simulated
distribution of $D^*$s.

Then returning `s.obs` to its original role as our observerd sample SD,
we obtain the 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI of the form
$\left(\frac{S_{obs}}{U^*},\frac{S_{obs}}{L^*}\right).$ In the R
code the suffix `.re` replaces the re-sampled quantities denoted above by $*$s.

This is called a nonparametric bootstrap because the bootstrap procedure has not
assumed that the data were sampled from a normal distribution (or another
distribution of known type). We have assumed only that our $n=100$ observations are randomly sampled from
some distribution for which the standard deviation exists.